# textBox to DateTime in DB

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datagridview

Iam trying to get a DateTime out of an textBox, where it allready is in Format of MySql DateTime. The column in the DB is also DateTime format.

However, when i press my button to save the Dates in the DB, the whole row is gonna get emptyed.

I tried around with different formats und DataTypes in DB without anny effect

```cs
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
    conn.Open();

    string startzeit = textBoxstartzeit.Text.ToString();
    DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(startzeit); 
    string stopzeit = textBoxstopzeit.Text.ToString();
    DateTime stop = DateTime.Parse(stopzeit);
    string pstartzeit = textBoxstopzeit.Text.ToString();
    DateTime pstart = DateTime.Parse(pstartzeit);
    string pstopzeit = textBoxstopzeit.Text.ToString();
    DateTime pstop = DateTime.Parse(pstopzeit);

    MySqlCommand cmdnew = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmdnew.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdnew.CommandText = "UPDATE arbeitszeiten SET astart = '" + start + "',  astop = '" + stop + "', pstart = '" + pstart + "', pstop = '" + pstop + "' WHERE id = '" + dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value + "'";
    cmdnew.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}

private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand feedstartzeit = conn.CreateCommand();
        feedstartzeit.CommandText = "SELECT astart FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE id = '" + dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value + "'";
        DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(feedstartzeit.ExecuteScalar());
        textBoxstartzeit.Text = start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        MySqlCommand feedstopzeit = conn.CreateCommand();
        feedstopzeit.CommandText = "SELECT astop FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE id = '" + dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value + "'";
        DateTime stop = Convert.ToDateTime(feedstopzeit.ExecuteScalar());
        textBoxstopzeit.Text = stop.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        MySqlCommand feedstartpause = conn.CreateCommand();
        feedstartpause.CommandText = "SELECT pstart FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE id = '" + dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value + "'";
        DateTime startpause = Convert.ToDateTime(feedstartpause.ExecuteScalar());
        textBoxstartpause.Text = startpause.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        MySqlCommand feedstoppause = conn.CreateCommand();
        feedstoppause.CommandText = "SELECT pstop FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE id = '" + dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value + "'";
        DateTime stoppause = Convert.ToDateTime(feedstoppause.ExecuteScalar());
        textBoxstoppause.Text = stoppause.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Bitte ID auswählen", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Button4 is the upload new data and the dataGridView part is filling the textBoxes with a preformated datetime that later get uploaded by button4

Comment: Why you're using a `TextBox` instead of a `DateTime` component? Use a `DateTimePicker` then you don't need to convert a string to date.

Comment: because i also need the time in there

Comment: What sort of UI is this? `DateTimePicker` in WinForms can handle the time as well, for example.

Comment: As a side-note, I'd **very strongly** advise you to stop doing SQL like this - use parameterized SQL instead, as otherwise you're opening yourself up to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @JonSkeet you can ? i do not see that ^^

Comment: From the docs, emphasis mine: "Represents a Windows control that allows the user to select a date **and a time** and to display the date and time with a specified format."

Comment: about the sql injection .. yeah got mentioned a couple a times but i dont see the need as it is a private project

Comment: Nope, you can change the format to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom` and set the custom format as `dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: "i dont see the need as it is a private project" - I'd very strongly urge you to get into good habits now. Why build up habits you already know are open to security breaches? You end up with cleaner code and fewer conversion issues by using parameterized SQL too.

Comment: @Sami but it does not allow me to choose the time then, right ? cause what i would change most of the time is the time it self, not the date

Comment: Another advantage of parameterized queries: If done right, you won't have to worry about how to format parameters in a way the DBMS likes it. That's all done for you under the hood. May as well help with you problem right now.

Comment: @JonSkeet allright can you give me an quick example of how parameterized sql ?

Comment: Only thing i remeber to have read according to that was soemthing with ... command.parameters.something(?,?)

Comment: I would start by searching for "c# parameterized sql mysql"

Comment: And yes, you can absolutely change the time with a DateTimePicker. I'd recommend setting the `Format` property to `DateTimePickerFormat.Time` rather than using a custom format though.

Comment: @JonSkeet format property.. now that i see it i feel realy dumb :D thanks. i think this will realy help (y)

Comment: @JonSkeet if you still active in the post: does the being better of with paramentes only count for inserts and update statements or also for the select request ?

Comment: @SvenRademacher: Everything. For example, if you're issuing a request and limiting the data by logged in user, it really doesn't help if they can bypass that via SQL injection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, the by Jon Skeet suggested parametered sql request solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your date time format should be your server date time format, if you want to use datetime then you should use datetime picker so you don't need to convert into datetime.